# Concatenation of values of the same column

Tags: java, jpa

I wrote following code with criteria query:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

    Root root = cq.from(Offer.class);
    Join recipients = root.join("recipients", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join items = recipients.join("items", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join category = items.join("category", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join superCategory = category.join("superCategory", JoinType.LEFT);

    cq.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
            root.get("id").alias("id"),
            criteriaBuilder.concat(
                    criteriaBuilder.concat(superCategory.get("name"), ": "),
                    criteriaBuilder.concat(items.get("item"), ", ")).alias("item")
    ));
    cq.distinct(true);
    cq.where(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(items.get("item")));
    cq.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("id")));
    List<Tuple> itemsResultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This query produces following result:

```
Id  | Item
----------------
1   | C1: Apple,        
1   | C2: Book,
1   | C3: Phone,
2   | C2: Book,
2   | C4: Pizza,
3   | C1: Apple,
5   | C3: Phone,
5   | C5: Car,
5   | C6: Tee, 
5   | C1: Apple,
```

What I want is to get the following result:

```
Id  | Item
-------------------------------------
1   | C1: Apple, C2: Book, C3: Phone,
2   | C2: Book, C4: Pizza,
3   | C1: Apple,
5   | C3: Phone, C5: Car, C6: Tee, C1: Apple,
```

How can I aggregate and concatenate the values of the same column (as shown above)?

Comment: have you looked at `group by`?

Comment: You *cannot* with plain JPQL. You will have to use database-specific functions, e.g. [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) in Oracle. You may be able to invoke it using the JPA 2.1 JPQL `FUNCTION`, although I am not sure that it does manage the peculiarities of the `LISTAGG ... WITHIN GROUP (...)` syntax. If you cannot use the `FUNCTION` keyword of JPQL, using a native query might be the only alternative (or execute the aggregation in Java).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will check what database-specific functions are offered in MS SQL but I think I am going to execute the aggregation in Java.